# Use of npm package within Flutter

Tags: node.js, react-native, flutter

I come from an Android native background and have recently started using Flutter more frequently, but I have no ReactNative experience whatsoever.

Is it at all possible to port an existing RN (npm-package) for use with a Flutter application? My understanding is that a RN compliant package exposes a JS API. Is there any way to implement a form of JS interop to achieve this, or is it not possible, and it would be better to ask the package vendor for Android and iOS specific native library / SDK releases (which were probably used to create the npm-package initially)?

My initial outlook was that it was not possible, but then I saw this article;
https://www.thesmythgroup.com/in-development/how-to-use-npm-packages-in-native-ios-apps/

Comment: It depends on what the package does.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the base conditions behind "depends"? The package provides SIP (VoIP telephony) functionality.

Comment: What i mean to say is that, you could make use of some of the code as it is in the npm package.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm kinda trying to figure out 'how' to approach "making use of some of the code". When extracting the tgz tarball, I see index.js, package.json and (in case of Android) some kotlin files and lib aar files. Where to begin?

Comment: Has any one figured it out and actually used the npm package inside flutter app ?

Comment: The outcome varies based on the package's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Dart and JavaScript represent distinct programming languages. While it may be feasible to convert your library from JS to Dart, it is a challenging and likely unsustainable endeavor, not easily adaptable to various scenarios.

Unless you possess proficiency in both languages and understand their limitations, it is advisable to avoid attempting the conversion of an NPM package to Dart code unless there are no alternative solutions available.

I strongly recommend considering rewriting the NPM package in Dart from scratch.

NOTE: This response assumes that your intention is not to incorporate JS code into a webview but rather utilize the code within the Dart VM.

The appropriate course of action depends on your specific goals.

Are you compiling your Flutter app for web deployment?

Dart's JS library may be the suitable option...

Are you targeting Android compilation?

In that case, alternatives such as Android JS, Flutter_liquidcore, and Interactive_WebView are worth exploring.

Your decision should be guided by the expectations you have for the application's intended platform.

However, it's crucial to manage your expectations and understand that a full native app experience may not be attainable...

Answer (score -2):

I would say it is better to use only dart packages, you don't have support for dart in npm, in some months you would have very big problems with that because of the lack of support, take that in mind...